# How to convert an "int" variable to vector iterator in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, static-cast

Imagine two nested loops each iterating with integer variables (let's say `i` and `j`). Inside these two loops, a function (`fun`) generates a vector (`vec`) using `i` and `j` as inputs. The generated vector has to be saved in a larger vector called `total`. I know that I can use `push_back` but I prefer to initialize my vector first (with static size). I tried to use `insert` but I don't know how can I convert `int` to `vector<int>::iterator`. I tried `static_cast<vector<int>::iterator>(2*i +j)` but it gives me this error:

`no suitable constructor exists to convert from "int" to "__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>>"`

```
using namespace std;
vector<double> total(M, 0); // Initilized with zeros

for (int i = 0; i < A; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < B; ++j)
    {
        vector<double> vec = fun(i);
        copy_n(vec.begin(), vec.size(), /* an iterator to where I want to save vec in total */);        
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `i` and `j` to `begin()`. Mission accomplished (this trick only works with vectors, and assumes that you're not exceeding the size of the underlying vector).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: It works with vector iterators, but not _only_ with vector iterators. It works with all random-access iterators including `deque::iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is `vec.begin() + 2*i + j`, but it'll work only for randomly accessible containers. For a generic solution you must use [`std::advance()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance)

```
auto v = vec.begin();
std::advance(v, 2*i + j);
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `copy_n` from the last iteration is the point where you should start inserting this iteration.

```
std::vector<double> total(M, 0); // Initilized with zeros
auto it = total.begin();

for (int i = 0; i < A; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < B; ++j)
    {
        auto vec = fun(i);
        it = std::copy_n(vec.begin(), vec.size(), it);
        // or it = std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), it);
    }
}
```